# convert post to pdf with custom layout

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I am using wordpress, and I want my post to be converted to pdf just like in [this website](http://www.ea-estate.com/index.php?site=2&lang=EN&refid=884) (click print icon to see what I mean). I want to do something like that in my [website](http://www.spanskeboliger.dk/property/naer-by-og-strand-3/). Can you share me an idea on how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin for wordpress here (it might be what you are looking for)

http://wordpress.org/plugins/kalins-pdf-creation-station/

Answer (score 0):

I use mPDF (www.mpdf1.com) as follows:

(1) Buffer the output using ob_start()

(2) Collect all the output into a variable $content = ob_getcontents()

(3) Flush the buffer to display the content on the screen using ob_flush()

(4) Create the PDF as a file

So something like this:

```
// Buffer the output so I can collect the html
ob_start();

// Do the display bit here

....

// Collect into a variable and flush it out
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_flush();

// Make a PDF
include "MPDF/mpdf.php";
$mpdf = new mPDF();

// Add some CSS to style content
$content = "<style>".file_get_contents("style.css").'</style>'.$content;

// Create PDF and save as file
$mpdf -> WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf -> Output('PDF/pdffile.pdf', 'F');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [PDF & PRINT BUTTON JOLIPRINT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/joliprint/)
2. [ANTHOLOGIZE](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/anthologize/)
3. [PRINT FRIENDLY AND PDF BUTTON](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/printfriendly/)
4. [PDF AND PPT VIEWER](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdf-and-ppt-viewer/)
5. [PDF24 ARTICLES TO PDF](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdf24-posts-to-pdf/)
6. [KALIN’S PDF CREATION STATION](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kalins-pdf-creation-station/)
7. [MAKE PDF NEWSPAPER](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/make-pdf-newspaper/)
8. [EMBED PDF](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dirtysuds-embed-pdf/)
9. [RV EMBED PDF](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rv-embed-pdf/)
10. [WORDPRESSPDF](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpresspdf/)
11. [GOOGLE DOCS VIEWER](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-docs-viewer/)
    12 [GOOGLE DOC EMBEDDER](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-document-embedder/)

Try above wordpress plugins...